# Creating a factor: error using the cut() function

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am receiving this `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: lengths of 'breaks' and 'labels' differ.` error when attempting to create a new variable that indicates if the Air Quality Index is greater than 50 for over 100 days.  Basically, I want to create a "yes" or "no" and label.

I watched a YouTube video for the cut() function. I have tried a few different variations of the breaks argument. I feel as if  am close, but I don't understand the error. The break should start at the min value and end at exactly 100. Anything over 100 to the max value should get a "yes"

Comment: Inside of `mutate`, you can reference your data's column names directly. Try simply `count` instead of `.$count`.

Comment: It didn't make a difference :/.

Comment: Please provide some sample data if `mutate_at` as shown below doesn't help you.

Comment: Use `dput(pmdata)` to provide some or all of the data in your dplyr chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `cut` function using `mutate_at`. The example with sample data is as below.

The count has been reduced to `4` to consider the label as "Yes" in sample data. In actual implementation it can be kept as 100.

```
df <- read.table(text = "AQI Date.Local year Latitude Longitude City.Name State.Name 
 38 01-01 2005 30.5 -87.9 Fairhope Alabama 
 56 01-04 2005 30.5 -87.9 Fairhope Alabama 
 30 01-07 2005 30.5 -87.9 Fairhope Alabama 
 36 01-10 2005 30.5 -87.9 Fairhope Alabama 
 14 01-13 2005 30.5 -87.9 Fairhope Alabama 
 32 01-16 2005 30.5 -87.9 Fairhope Alabama
 60 01-16 2005 30.5 -97.9 NewCity Alabama
 70 01-16 2005 30.5 -97.9 NewCity Alabama
 80 01-16 2005 30.5 -97.9 NewCity Alabama
 70 01-16 2005 30.5 -97.9 NewCity Alabama
 55 01-16 2005 30.5 -97.9 NewCity Alabama
                 ", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(Latitude, Longitude, year) %>%
  filter(AQI > 50) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  select(year, Latitude, Longitude, count) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(count), cut, 
            breaks = c(min(.), 4, max(.)), labels = c("No", "Yes"))  

#   year Latitude Longitude count 
#  <int>    <dbl>     <dbl> <fctr>
#1  2005     30.5     -97.9 Yes   
#2  2005     30.5     -87.9 No
```

Comment: This did not work.. I am basically going to be plotting the location (latitude and longitude) of the some plant... and altering the color of the points by showing if the mean AQI was above 50 for over 100 days. I am making 2 plots, for the year 2005 and the year 2014.

Comment: @Josh That's not expected though. The only way one can pin-point problem if you share whole or part of `pmdata`.

Comment: I am not really sure what more info I can give..                                          
                 - AQI: air quality index, the smaller the better air quality...
                  - Date.Local: the date when the measurement is collected
- year: 2005 or 2014
- Latitude: latitude of the location
- Longitude: longitude of the location
- City.Name
- State.Name.

Comment: is there anyway I can private message you?  I feel like my code is super close to what I need it to do.. I am only working with 7 variables within the pmdata set.. it contains over 500k observations.. I am not sure what's not expected?

Comment: @Josh You can simply run `head(pmdata)` on command line and share the output. I can show my answer working based on sample data. If that doesn't work you can send me message.

Comment: I would prefer to PM.      ```        
   AQI Date.Local  year Latitude Longitude City.Name State.Name
  <int> <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>     <chr>     
1    38 01-01       2005     30.5     -87.9 Fairhope  Alabama   
2    32 01-04       2005     30.5     -87.9 Fairhope  Alabama   
3    30 01-07       2005     30.5     -87.9 Fairhope  Alabama   
4    36 01-10       2005     30.5     -87.9 Fairhope  Alabama   
5    14 01-13       2005     30.5     -87.9 Fairhope  Alabama   
6    32 01-16       2005     30.5     -87.9 Fairhope  Alabama ```

Comment: sorry I am relatively new to stackoverflow. I don't know how to PM....I don't have enough reputation to "chat". I edited my original post.

Comment: @Josh I modified sample data from you to include few entries with `AQI` more than 50. In current implementation `Yes` is shown if count is more than `4`. You can change it to `100` in your case. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @KMR woo! it worked, do you have any idea why my code was not running? I have not learned about mutate_at() or vars().. I feel like I was close..

Comment: @Josh Good. If you are happy then you can accept my answer by clicking on `tick` icon in left side of answer box. Let me review why your code was not running.

Comment: @Josh Seems you have remove the `accepted answer tick` now. May be it would have been by mistake. You can correct if that is by mistake.

Comment: sorry that was a mistake.. my internet was being slow. I am still trying to figure out why my code did not run. oh welll